# define a new column and give the values base on the each group in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

"Consider the following dataset:

```
a    b    c   
e1   21   99  
e1   21   99  
e2   22   99
e3   23   99
e1   23   99
e3   24   99
e4   27   99
e1   25   99
e2   29   99
e4   22   99
e2   23   99
```

I want to have a new column based on the column "a" as bellow:

```
a      b    c    d
e_11   21   99   1
e_11   21   99   1
e_21   22   99   2
e_31   23   99   3
e_11   23   99   1
e_31   24   99   3
e_41   27   99   4
e_11   25   99   1
e_21   29   99   2
e_41   22   99   4
e_21   23   99   2
```

I need to add a new column d and give the same value if they belong to the same group.
I do not know how filter my data by each group and set the same value for each group. 
here is my code which does not give me the right answer:

```
i=0
e=[]
 for name in df.groupby('a'):
  for j in range(len(name)):

    e.append(i)
 i++

df['d'] = pd.Series(e)
print(df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703634/pandas-group-by-and-assign-a-group-id-then-ungroup/47703735#47703735, multiple ways to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have both your requirements in one go would be:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'(?V1)(?<=[a-z])(?=\d+)')
def splitter(row):
    (char, number) = rx.split(row['a'])
    return pd.Series({'a': '{}_{}{}'.format(char, number, number), 'd': number})

df[['a', 'd']] = df.apply(splitter, axis = 1)
```

---

Which yields using `df.head()`:

```
    a       b   c   d
0   e_11    21  99  1
1   e_11    21  99  1
2   e_22    22  99  2
3   e_33    23  99  3
4   e_11    23  99  1
```

---

The idea here is to set up a `splitter` function which splits between letters and numbers. The function is applied row-wise and gives back the new columns. You'll need the newer `regex` module for empty splits to work.