# Method for mapping strings to numerical values on all columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

My test and training data has several columns, where the values are taken from a limited set of strings, for instance:

```
Gas
TypeA
TypeB
TypeA
TypeC
TypeA
```

or

```
CentralisedHeating
Yes
No
```

In order to fit some models on this data, I would need to convert these strings into numerical values, like this:

```
Gas
0
1
0
2
0
```

However, because I have many columns like these, it would very cumbersome to go through each column and create encodings.

Is there some function in `scikit-learn` or `pandas` or `numpy` which I could use to just transform the string values into numerical ones?

I would need to apply the same mapping both on the training data and the test data.

I am currently reading and storing my data like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_train = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('../input/test.csv')
```

Comment: maybe i don't understand, but couldn't you just apply a function to the dataframe?

Comment: Apply a function that takes in what and returns what?

Comment: One that does this encoding bit for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703634/pandas-group-by-and-assign-a-group-id-then-ungroup/47703735#47703735, there are more than 5 methods for you