# Creating a new column assigning same index to repeated values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

How can I generate a new column listing repeated values? For example, my dataframe is:

```
id    color

123   white
123   white
123   white
345   blue
345   blue
678   red
```

This is the desired output:

```
#    id   color

1   123   white
1   123   white
1   123   white 
2   345   blue
2   345   blue
3   678   red
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas group by and assign a group id then ungroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703634/pandas-group-by-and-assign-a-group-id-then-ungroup)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check with`factorize`

```
df['#']=df.id.factorize()[0]+1
df
    id  color  #
0  123  white  1
1  123  white  1
2  123  white  1
3  345   blue  2
4  345   blue  2
5  678    red  3
```

Another method

```
df.groupby('id').ngroup()+1
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
dtype: int64
```

To add it to the first positon:

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='#', value=df.id.factorize()[0]+1)
df
   #   id  color 
0  1  123  white  
1  1  123  white  
2  1  123  white  
3  2  345   blue  
4  2  345   blue  
5  3  678    red
```

Comment: Is there any way to generate the new column at the beginning of the df?

Comment: @Guerra check with insert ~

Comment: last method is not working. "#" doen'ts start at 1 and it has disordered values

Answer (score 4):

You can also use categorical codes:

```
df['id'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
dtype: int8
```